# Custom UICollectionViewLayout with left docked header in vertical scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am new to custom UICollectionView layouts and just wanted to get some feedback as to how I would go about creating a layout such as this:

[image]

The header height would span the height of the cells in that section, and each cell would have a fixed height.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S placement of the header is the most important. The footer would likely only be a line separator.

Comment: Is the height of the cell the same for each one?

Comment: @Larme Yes, same height for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` for this. You can try using [DateFlowLayout](https://gist.github.com/vigorouscoding/5155703), it is a flexible subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.